# How can I have the same weight in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[sfdefault, ultralight]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\begin{document}
Marieke is the best \\[14pt]
${x = \dfrac{a + b}{2}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no “light” version of Fira Math.

Comment: So I can't get the same weight in math-mode?

Comment: Not unless you find a lightweight version of Fire Math. A light version of a font is not something that is just generated.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This uses the light text font for some ranges and a grey coloured math font so it doesn't look quite so bold (for the + here)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}
\usepackage[sfdefault, ultralight]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Color=gray]{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range={up,it}]{FiraSans-UltraLight.otf}
\begin{document}
Marieke is the best \\[14pt]
${x = \dfrac{a + b}{2}}$

\end{document}
```